# Merge audio file one top on other file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova-plugins, audio-recording

Is it possible to merge audio file,one top of the other audio files, using JavaScript on client side  rather than server side and   can be saved has one file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: @Nitish,i am using the cordova media plugin to record the user voice, i need to add background sound to recorded voice,i just want to know is it possible in client side to add background music using javascript.?